# Spring jdbc template '?' placeholder screening

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

In my project I use Spring JDBC template and PostgreSQL. I use following code to check does specified column exist in JSON field or not

```
encode(configuration, 'escape') :: JSONB ? 'accountsIds'
```

[Here is a link where you can find information about what does '?' in PostgreSQL do](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html)

I use named parameters also, so in this case spring jdbc give me following 
error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Not allowed to mix named and traditional ? placeholders.

But '?' is not a placeholder here it's a part of PostgreSQL syntax.

Is there any way to say spring jdbc that '?' is not a placeholder ?

Comment: It's a general problem with JDBC, not sure if that is actually related to JDBC Template, But you can use `??` instead

Comment: See e.g. here: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAFxe7BBHtgryUVZtrjKH3Bw9Ms7jkEL5KAz_Ui67Q%3DsFyBXSiw%40mail.gmail.com#CAFxe7BBHtgryUVZtrjKH3Bw9Ms7jkEL5KAz_Ui67Q=sFyBXSiw@mail.gmail.com